# How can I write Bulk Data on an Excel Sheet using Python, Django, MySql, Dataframe?

Tags: django, python-3.x, dataframe, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Python. I am using Python with Django and MySql
I have written a code to fetch bulk data (2.5 million) from MySql database and split it into three variables and then write them on an Excel sheet which contains 3 sub sheets. Here is my view.py file.

```
all_dataobj=fetchdata.objects.all()
pserializer=fetchdataSerializers(all_dataobj,many=True)

res = [item for item in pserializer.data if 1 <= item.get('id') <= 1000000]   
res1 = [item for item in pserializer.data if 1 <= item.get('id') > 1000000 and item.get('id') <= 2000000 ]  
res2 = [item for item in pserializer.data if 1 <= item.get('id') > 2000000]   

df = pd.DataFrame([])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])

df = df.append(res)
df1 = df1.append(res1)
df2 = df2.append(res2)

writer = ExcelWriter('fetchdata_sheet12.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2',index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet3',index=False)

writer.save()
```

But this code works totally fine with less data. When I am running it for 2.5 million data, the browser keeps on running and no excel sheet gets generated.

Comment: 1) Did you check your df, df1, df2 are empty or not ?                                                                2) Did you try this ? -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: Yes I have checked ...df, df1 and df2 are not empty. Actully when I am using this code for bulk data my code is working...excel sheet is also getting generated...but it is taking too much time...like more than one hour for 2500000 data...which is not right...it should take 10 to 15 mins maximum...and one more thing ...my RAM is 8 GB...so when I am running the code in chrome, I have checked in Task Manager ...Python is taking more than 6 GB to compute...so any suggestions please?????@adnan kaya